# How can I continue a loop in bash after an application returned an error?

Tags: bash, wget

I save images with:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..30000}
do
    wget "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/3809_obj_sprite.gif?id="$i
done
```

Is there a way to speed up the process? Sometimes a URL does not exist and I get:

```
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not found
2012-08-04 18:09:36 ERROR 404: Not found.
```

How can I continue after this error?

Comment: If you have an additional question about how to download out only certain object, please ask an additional question. Mixing two subjects in one question just over-complicates the matter :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - Your comment is spot on. But you chose to edit the title to reflect the question *you* answered. Neglecting to notice that there where two answers answering his other question.

Comment: @Nifle: Feel free to read the history of the question and change it if you feel that I've missed the point with my edit. Also, please note that I edited and commented on the question *before* I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
wget "http://s.../m=itemdb_rs/3809_obj_sprite.gif?id="$i || true
```

This way, if `wget` fails, the result of that line is still zero and your script continues.

To learn how to **properly** handle errors in a bash script, check out the following resources:

- [Error handling in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786/error-handling-in-bash)
- [Bash: Error handling](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..30000};
do 
x="http://64.79.147.130/m=itemdb_rs/3809_obj_sprite.gif?id="$i
if [[ $(echo $(GET -sd $x | grep "404")) = "" ]]; 
then 
wget --no-dns-cache -nc -U"Firefox/10" $x 2>&1 \
| grep "Saving" | sed 's,Saving to,Saved,'; 
fi 
done
```